# Convert Ecto Query into a map

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

When using `Ecto.Query` and also the `from()` api, is there a way to turn the result of Enums/List into a map?

```
getData()
|> Repo.all()

...

def getData do
  from (e in Example, select ... where ...
end
```

This returns something like

```
[%{data1: data, data2: data}]
```

How can I convert this to a map like

```
%{data1: data, data2: data}
```

I tried

```
getData()
|> Repo.all()
|> Enum.into(%{})
```

but that doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

How/where would you like to use the output?

if you have only one record in the output, then use Repo.one, instead of Repo.all and it will deliver you results as %{}.

On the other side if you are seeking to get just from
[%{data1: data, data2: data}] -> %{data1: data, data2: data}, use something like

```
[x] = 
  getData()
  |> Repo.all()
```

"x" will be what you desire but it makes no sense if you expect multiple rows, as you need to keep it together in some kind of list... and if you expect one row, then as already stated above use Repo.one.